# SwiftUI 1.0: Save custom Datatype in CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, custom-data-type

I in my current project I want to save a custom data type in core data but I don't know to do it.

The Core Data Entity:

```
extension WorkoutBuy {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WorkoutBuy> {
    return NSFetchRequest<WorkoutBuy>(entityName: "WorkoutBuy")
}

@NSManaged public var beschreibung: String?
@NSManaged public var dauerInterval: Int64
@NSManaged public var dauerPause: Int64
@NSManaged public var dauerPauseDurchgang: Int64
@NSManaged public var durchgaenge: Int64
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
@NSManaged public var intensitaet: String?
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var price: Double
@NSManaged public var catagory: Catagory? !!!//here is my own data type !!!

}

extension WorkoutBuy : Identifiable {

}
```

My own data type:

```
struct Catagory: Codable, Identifiable{
   let id: Int
   let localizedString: String
   let engishName: String?
}
```

When I do it this way I get this error:

> Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type

And:

> Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance.

PS: I use the AppDelegate to create the persistentContainer

**EDIT**

When Catagory is a own core data entity the app is starting but when I add an object I got the following error like 10 times in the console:

> 2020-12-04 21:58:31.586858+0100 IntervallTraining[4869:1923447] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x2812c9380> ,  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x2812c9380> ,  threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
> Ein Core Data-Fehler ist aufgetreten.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Create an extra entity. 2) Declare `category` as `String` and encode the struct instance to JSON. The first error can be fixed by declaring `Category` as `public` or the `@NSManaged` properties as `internal`.

Comment: @vadian I tried your first suggestion earlier. With I create a new core data entity for catagory I dont get an error but when I add a new object I get many errors in the terminal and the data isn't save. I will to an edit. Maybe you have a solution...

Comment: You will find the easiest way around this is to create an entity that duplicates your `Catagory` struct and then link it to the other entity through a one to one relationship. Core Data is finicky with custom classes.

Comment: Thank you @Yrb. I have never work with relationships. Do you have a good tutorial?

Comment: [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/overview)